# How do I optimize this planar object's vertices?

Tags: mesh, optimization

So in a nutshell I want to optimize the vertices in my object, more in some parts and less in others:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jvrh6rbrnbQ

Currently the object is planar, but I do want to solidify it later. I've looked through all the context menu tools when in the different edit modes (vertex,edge,face). And tried a bunch of those commands but nothing really worked.

(This is my first real scene so yeah n00b alert)

The file itself is [here](http://sydneyband.com.au/3d/blender/icon.blend).

Comment: first you could delete a lot of vertices with the Select > Checker Deselect function, and choose its parameters in the Operator box, then maybe delete faces only and bridge edge loops? Maybe share your file to have a look?

Comment: what is your final goal exactly? As I said you could try Checker Deselect, also X > Limit Dissolve to eliminate a lot of vertices, then you'll need to adapt the topology to your needs, but you can keep a lot of useless vertices if it doesn't change anything to the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have something of [a solution here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xBlsSekWyM0).

Basically use Vertex → Merge Vertices → By Distance, and then play with the distance parameter till you get what you need. Careful though, it can destroy sharp edges if you're not careful.

What this solution has over the checkerboard idea is evening out the distribution of vertices. Which is what I wanted.